# Spark Incorrectly Reading CSV

Tags: python, scala, csv, apache-spark

I want to read train.csv in spark, but it appears that spark is somehow incorrectly reading the file. I read the csv into pandas with python, and it shows the correct value of 1 as the first entry in project_is_approved. When I read the csv with spark (scala) I get a string, presumably that is from elsewhere in the dataset.

Why is this happening? Most examples use the syntax I use to read a csv.

```
jakeu123@azure3:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> f = requests.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hdbltrl8bh6kbu/train.csv?raw=1", stream=True)
>>> with open("train.csv", "w") as csv:
...     csv.write(f)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
>>> with open("train.csv", "w") as csv:
...     csv.write(f.content)
... 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
>>> df[["project_is_approved"]].head(1)
   project_is_approved
0                    1
>>> 
jakeu123@azure3:~$ ./spark/bin/spark-shell
2018-06-07 23:55:02 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2018-06-07 23:55:09 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
2018-06-07 23:55:09 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
Spark context Web UI available at http://azure3:4042
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1528415709241).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("train.csv")
2018-06-07 23:55:27 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, teacher_id: string ... 14 more fields]

scala> df.select($"project_is_approved").show(1)
+--------------------+                                                          
| project_is_approved|
+--------------------+
|I currently have ...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row


scala> :quit
```

Comment: Your data  uses `"` as the escape character and contains embedded new line characters. You can use `options(Map("header" -> "true", "escape" -> "\"", "multiLine" -> "true"))`. Also please don't use external hosting for data. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define escape character so that comma(,) inside text can be ignored while parsing

this can be done as

```
spark.read.option("escape","\"")
```

working example :

```
scala> val df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("escape","\"").csv("train.csv");

            df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, teacher_id: string ... 14 more fields]

            scala> df.select($"project_is_approved").show
            +-------------------+
            |project_is_approved|
            +-------------------+
            |                  1|
            |                  0|
            |                  1|
            |                  0|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  0|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  1|
            |                  0|
            +-------------------+
            only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: I think you should add multiline option as well, as recommended by alpert (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3269809/alper-t-turker)

Comment: @Norman, I am having the same issue with a multi-paragraph string column in a csv file.  Would escaping on a space solve that or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, spark can't directly read a file in URL format. So instead of reading CSV file with python and write it to disk so you can read it later using spark, you can use pandas before convert it to Spark Dataframe (which you will get the benefit of distributed computation on spark by using dataframe)

I'm not really familiar with Scala so I tried to solve it using pyspark

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, LongType

frame = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hdbltrl8bh6kbu/train.csv?raw=1", index_col=None, header=0, encoding='utf-8') # Prod
frame = frame.where(pd.notnull(frame), None) # Fill NaN with Null

schema = StructType([
  StructField("id", StringType(), True),
  StructField("teacher_id", StringType(), True),
  StructField("teacher_prefix", StringType(), True),
  StructField("school_state", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_submitted_datetime", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_grade_category", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_subject_categories", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_subject_subcategories", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_title", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_essay_1", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_essay_2", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_essay_3", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_essay_4", StringType(), True),
  StructField("project_resource_summary", StringType(), True),
  StructField("teacher_number_of_previously_posted_projects", LongType(), True),
  StructField("project_is_approved", LongType(), True),
                    ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(frame, schema)
```

Oh btw I think providing the schema in reading CSV file is a must since it won't kick any spark job so you can avoid wasted computation resource and the spark will read the file in the correct format